# Arranging Font Awesome Icons

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

Using Wordpress, I have added a Custom HTML Widget into my footer which I am using for some Font Awesome icon links.  My code is as follows:

```
<div style="float:right;margin-top:17px">
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 1</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 2</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 3</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 4</a>
</div>
```

This worked great.  They sat where I wanted them too within my footer and they displayed in order, 1 through 4.  But then I was asked to add a 5th icon, this time a phone icon with popup to display the client's phone number.

So my code became:

```
<div class="footerSocialWidgets">
    <div class="widgetPhoneTooltip">
        <a href="">Phone Font Awesome Icon</a>
        <span class="widgetPhoneTooltipText">PHONE NUMBER</span>
    </div>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 1</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 2</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 3</a>
    <a href="">Font Awesome Icon 4</a>
</div>
```

My CSS for this is as follows:

```
.footerSocialWidgets {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 17px;
}

.widgetPhoneTooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.widgetPhoneTooltip .widgetPhoneTooltipText {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    top: -5px;
    right: 105%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.widgetPhoneTooltip:hover .widgetPhoneTooltipText {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

It all works great except for the fact that no matter what I try, the new phone icon is ALWAYS the last icon.  And because of the constraints within the page, I kind of need it to display as the first icon so I can have the text popup display from the left.

As per the below image, the phone icon is stuck on the far right.  No matter what I try however, I cannot coax it to the left into the space currently occupied by the Facebook icon.  That way, the text popup will display out the left of the icon and won't interfere with anything else.  I just don't know what I can change in order to change the phone icons location.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: This is how it is currently displayed]

EDIT: I am still having troubles.  I changed the first div to a class selector just to make it cleaner, though I just transferred that same CSS.

EDIT 2: It is the Phone icon DIV causing the issue.  I just left the font awesome icon alone and it appeared on the left as expected.  I then stripped off the selected class within the DIV (widgetPhoneTooltip), just leaving a standard DIV and it still did it.

Comment: By running your exact code through JsFiddle the phone does display first. So you're missing something out in the provided details. Check if for some reason `float:right` is not being applied to the icon

Comment: did you target divs with float:right? because this exact thing should be working fine